# Loop through items before rendering pdf and populating table using pdfkit and Django

Tags: python, django, pdfkit

I'm trying to export all of my users and data related to them in a rendered pdf. I'm struggling to loop over all my users and creating new table rows for each user. As per now the loop loops over all users, but it only populates the table with the data of the last user registered.

I do not think I'm able to use Django's conventional way of for looping, at least I cannot figure out how to pass context to the template.

#### views.py

```py
def users_export(request):
    users = User.objects.all()

    # Populate template tags in generated pdf with data
    data = dict()
    for user in users:
        data['full_name'] = user.get_full_name

    # Getting template, and rendering data
    template = get_template('backend/users/users_export.html')
    html = template.render(data)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)

    # Function for creating file name
    # Inner function
    def create_file_name():
        file_name = 'users %s.pdf' % (timezone.now())
        return file_name.strip()

    filename = create_file_name()

    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
    
    return response
```

#### users_export.html

```html
<table>
   <tr class="thead">
       <th class="text-left">Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td class="text-left">{{ full_name }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping the users correctly, but saving it in the dictionary the wrong way.
You are overriding the full_name key each time. You should use an unique value from the user as key and the full name as value

```
data = dict()

for user in users:
   user[user.username] = user.full_name
```

Also, I don't know about pdfkit, but assuming it's similar to Jinja or django template, you will need to loop through all the items.

Another option is to simply pass a list of full names instead of a dictionary

```
data = [user.full_name for user in users]
```

Edit:

Generate you also need to change your template and how you pass the data to the render function.

Try this:

```
html = template.render({"users": data})
```

Template

```
<table>
   <tr class="thead">
       <th class="text-left">Name</th>
   </tr>
   {% for user in users %} // this is assuming that you are using the list
   <tr>
       <td class="text-left">{{ user }}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. I've run into a few problems with you solution: pdfkit seems to need the parameter after [data] to be able to populate the pdf with data. Is there another way to loop without overriding the value each time? With passing the list instead the problem is that all data is returned in one row.